# Explanation of performance graph of FPGA design

Tags: fpga, performance

After implementing a mathematical function on a FPGA chip. The following graph shows for ~40 inputs the time response, i.e. how long it took to get the output calculated. This data is part of the results of the simulation, which took every input from \$0\$ to \$2^{32}-1\$ (the input and output are integers), so to emphasize the question, only a portion was put into the image.

[image]

The y-axis are the times of execution in ns, the x-axis are the input values. Now, can someone explain the spikes in the graph, i.e. the alternating ups and downs? What could influence such behavior?

The function, this chip implements, is of the form $$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^x{\frac{g(k)}{h(k)}}$$ for the input x, where both g(k) and h(k) are polynomial functions. The total complexity of the operation is $$O(x \log x)$$

PS: The FPGA is Altera Cyclone II, if it has any impact on the answer.

Comment: You will have to look at the details of the implementation, but in general division takes a variable amount of time to complete.

Comment: I've been told the same thing, also that multiplication is a constant time operation. But I couldn't find any technical/scientific papers that elaborate the matter in some detail, do you happen to know any?

Comment: Why does it take a variable amount of time to divide? Recall long division. Try to divide 1 by 2 using the long division technique. It will converge to 0.5 after one iteration (quick). Now try dividing 1 by 3 with the same method, assume you can stop after 20 digits. It took much longer, right?

Comment: In general there are 2 kinds of division algorithms for hardware: digit recurrence (basically long division, with some potential for enhancements) or functional iteration (see Newton-Raphson method, there are others). The latter type can produce results constant in the precision of the inputs, but they are generally less preferred to implement in hardware (area / power, but also latency concerns)

Comment: @EvanW - maybe you could put your comments into an answer?

Answer (score 1):

By taking a look into the [Cyclone II arquitecture](http://www.altera.com/literature/hb/cyc2/cyc2_cii51002.pdf) description I believe there is no hardware divider in the architecture. This would mean division is somehow implemented in software, potentially in non-constant time; whereas in hardware it should have been constant time.

I tried to find out how division is implemented in Altera boards but I couldn't. This can depend on whether *megafuncions* are being used or if it is a block such as [these](ftp://ftp.altera.com/pub/lit_req/document/fs/fsdiv_01.pdf).